# Html2Canvas Not Capturing Image in Shopify

Tags: javascript, shopify, html2canvas

I am attempting to convert the contents of a div into an image using Html2Canvas.

I developed the following coded and it works perfectly locally.

**Index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="html2canvas.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#" onclick="UploadImage();">upload file</a>
    <div id="dpo_base_image">
        <img src="Images/Lowen Glas.jpg" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
<script src="ImageUploader.js"></script>
```

**ImageUploader.js**

```
function UploadImage() {
    html2canvas(document.querySelector("#dpo_base_image")).then(canvas => {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "https://shopiflistener.azurewebsites.net/api/ImageUpload",
            data: canvas.toDataURL(),
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data.ImageDatabaseId);
            },
            error: function (data) { alert("Error") }
        });
    });
}
```

I now attempting to port this code into a Shopify Theme.

I have added the main html2canvas.js as an asset and linked to it in the header of the liquid theme.
I have added a link to the JQuert CDN.

And this is the "final" code in Shopify that just doesn't work:

```
debugger;
try {
    if ($("#Image15346471927913").length) {

        html2canvas($("#Image15346471927913"), {
            onrendered: function (canvas) {
                debugger;
                var img = canvas.toDataURL();
                alert(img);
            }
        });
    }
    else {
        console.log("Image div missing!");
    }
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
}
});
```

When debugging it gets to the line where it html2canvas attempts to convert the div to an image, pauses briefly and then skips out of the function. I can't get it to hit the catch or log any errors to the console.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Update:**

As per the comments I have swapped back to this and it still doesn't work.
It gets to the line that proves the image exists and then just jumps to the bottom line

```
jQuery(window).on('dpo_before_form_submit', function (e, form) {
    debugger;
    try {
        if ($("#Image15376602267753").length) {
         html2canvas(document.querySelector("#Image15376602267753")).then(canvas => {
                this.alert("Hello!");
            });
        }
        else {
            console.log("Image div missing!");
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

Comment: Why did you use **onrendered** in Shopify and not do it using Promises as you did in `ImageUploader.js` ? [Replace onrendered by then Promise](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues/674)

Comment: @BilalAkbar thanks for taking the time to look. I have tried it both ways and just cannot get it to work. I have added an update with the code.